# Is it possible to set linux user's priority?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-management

I am on Ubuntu system, and I want to create "limited" user. I want all processes started by this user to have lower than normal priority. It would be great if I/O priority could be decreased as well (but it is not a must).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do do this using Pluggable Authentication Module (PAM) limits.  See [this link](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_limits.html).  The default configuration file is /etc/security/limits.conf

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

If ubuntu has file `/etc/security/limits.conf` like fedora then you can define the limits without any problem. See if that file exists. There is extensive help and examples in the file that you will understand how to define limit. Specifically you want to assign max priority limit for some user.